# Python: How to loop correctly?

Tags: python, loops, if-statement

I'm trying to get a nested loop to work correctly but I'm having a lot of trouble with it.
I have a working code with lists but I want to add an else statement that declares a choice invalid and to try again and then exit and return to the first loop but I can't seem to get it to work without it repeating the invalid print code for every item in the list.
Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?
What works:

```
myNames = ["Jim", "Sarah", "Jason", "Lynne", "Ginny", "Joe", "Susan"]
myScores = [88, 92, 95, 84, 85, 92, 89]

print ("Student names: Jim, Sarah, Jason, Lynne, Ginny, Joe, Susan")
name = input("Please enter a students name to find their score or q to quit: ")

while name != 'q':
        for x in range(7):
            if myNames[x] == name:
                print(myNames[x])
                print(myScores[x])
        name = input("Please enter a students name to find their score or q to quit: ")
```

What doesn't work:

```
myNames = ["Jim", "Sarah", "Jason", "Lynne", "Ginny", "Joe", "Susan"]
myScores = [88, 92, 95, 84, 85, 92, 89]

print ("Student names: Jim, Sarah, Jason, Lynne, Ginny, Joe, Susan")
name = input("Please enter a students name to find their score or q to quit: ")

while name != 'q':
        for x in range(7):
            if myNames[x] == name:
                print(myNames[x])
                print(myScores[x])
            else:
                print("Invalid name please try again")
        name = input("Please enter a students name to find their score or q to quit: ")
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.
"doesn't work" is not a problem specification.

Comment: Youre probably looking for "break" which skips the rest of the for loop https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/break.html

Comment: You will actually need two `break` statements ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your program checks the entered name against every one of the acceptable names and prints a message for every mismatch.  Instead you need to print the message only if *all* the comparisons fail.  Here is one way to do that:

```
myNames = ["Jim", "Sarah", "Jason", "Lynne", "Ginny", "Joe", "Susan"]
myScores = [88, 92, 95, 84, 85, 92, 89]

print ("Student names: Jim, Sarah, Jason, Lynne, Ginny, Joe, Susan")
name = input("Please enter a students name to find their score or q to quit: ")

while name != 'q':
        for x in range(7):
            if myNames[x] == name:
                print(myNames[x])
                print(myScores[x])
                break
        else:
            print("Invalid name please try again")
        name = input("Please enter a students name to find their score or q to quit: ")
```

The break statement immediately exits the loop when it gets executed.  In the Python for:else: construct, the else: branch is taken only when the loop runs all the way through its elements without ever hitting a break statement.  So the error message prints only when *all* the comparisons fail.